# Paypal payflow pro in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new in **PayPal PayFlow pro** payment gateway please help how to integrate with Asp.net MVC

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

follow this link to implement **PayPal Pay flow** pro payment gateway in Asp.net

https://www.paypal.com/li/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-set-up-and-process-an-api-call-using-the-payflow-.net-sdk-ts1508